# A server with the specified hostname could not be found crashlytics

Tags: ios, jenkins, localhost, crashlytics

I am running iOS project job on Jenkins. It is a multiple-target scheme. I have unchecked parallelize build. Is worked just fine until last week. I keep getting those messages:

```
2014-05-31 14:42:44.788 run[62805:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.8
2014-05-31 14:42:56.193 run[62805:507] 

Crashlytics: Could not be onboarded statusCode 0 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x10061ae00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x10061cca0 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/ios/apps/com.contagme.Tbusiness/built, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/ios/apps/com.contagme.Tbusiness/built, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}
2014-05-31 14:43:02.951 run[62805:507] 

Crashlytics: business.app.dSYM could not be uploaded statusCode 0 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x10023ffb0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x100221170 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/api/v1/8b3cc2afd185191b47ce70547f29a014d00fff47/dsyms, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.crashlytics.com/api/v1/8b3cc2afd185191b47ce70547f29a014d00fff47/dsyms, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}
```

My intepretation:

Crashlytics server cannot be reached. What can I do? Is there any way how to deploy crashlytics and not having to rely on connectivity at the moment? Is the unreachability of crashlytics server really the source of this issue?

Comment: Try changing your network connection, I was getting same issue and change my wifi and then it start working fine. 